# How to encode / decode to show that both "strings" are the same?

Tags: python, unicode, decode, encode

In my program I compare string with unicode and for most of the cases it works fine (I get True, as expected).

```
'Home' == u'Home'
```

returns true.

However, the following two object are considered to be different:

> te®
>
> te┬«

The first of the unicode and another one is tring.

These objects are supposed to be the same. Is there a way to transform one of the object such that the comparison returns true?

By the way, the comparison returns the following error message:

> UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both
>   arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, comparisons will use ASCII as the default codec. Use the *actual* codec to explicitly decode the bytestring when comparing.

You'll have to figure out the correct codec first though, which is context dependent. If your data came from a URL for example, the server may have given you the correct codec in the content-type header. If it comes from an XML document, use an XML parser that'll heed the encoding information that is part of the XML document, etc.

In your case, you appear to have UTF8, if you interpret the second string as a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) of UTF-8 bytes decoded as [codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) or [codepage 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850):

```
>>> print u'te®'.encode('utf8').decode('cp437')
te┬«
```

It may be a different codepage still, but you shouldn't really print bytestrings to your Windows console to determine their contents *anyway*. Always use the `repr()` function when debugging:

```
>>> print repr(u'te®'.encode('utf8'))
'te\xc2\xae'
```

This shows you Python literal syntax to re-create the value, with any non-printable non-ASCII bytes represented by escape sequences for easy copying.